# Angular6 - Vertical scroll is not coming in responsive view

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I made an angular app and used ng-bootstrap with it, its responsive but issue I am facing is when I do zoom 100%/125% for ipad or ipad-pro I am not getting scroll bar and because of it footer is hidden.

My app.component.html is

```
<navbar></navbar>
<admin></admin>
<footer></footer>
```

Please let me know if I need to add some additional CSS to app.component.css or styles.css

my angular.json file is

```
"styles": [


  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
  "src/styles.css"

            ],
```

I tried changing the order of styles too but no luck

Comment: What do your styles look like? Mind providing a demo? :)

Comment: I didn't do any styling, used all the bootstrap components like, navbar, carousel, modal, alert, tool tip

Comment: Can you please provide your `index.html`